# Can you create a class before exporting it in typescript/angular? | TSLint: unused expression, expected an assignment or function call

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I come from the react world - I'm pretty familiar with the basic concepts of starting an app through an `index.js` and not having to deal with any html or anything. Within those javascript files that define views, they're all made available to each other via `import` and `export`, where `export default` means the default import will be that object, and just `export` allows for the possibility of importing multiple objects from the same file.

With all of that said, is everything that different in angular?

While I was trying to learn it, I tried to do something simple and create a logging class, which has got to be simple enough, right. So it looks like this, and this is how I would have written it in React:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
class LoggerService {
  info(msg: any) {
    console.log(msg);
  }

  warn(msg: any) {
    console.warn(msg);
  }

  error(msg: any) {
    console.error(msg);
  }
}

export LoggerService;
```

However, when I do that my TSLint kicks in and warns me about

> TSLint: unused expression, expected an assignment or function call...

on the last line. Can I not create classes before exporting them?

I know that every tutorial I've seen includes everything inside the export class, which I'm not used to (and so that's why I was trying to do it the other way) but if that's just Angular best practice then so be it.

**TLDR why am i getting an error with the above code**

Comment: You should instead write `export class LoggerService { ... }`

Comment: well i know that, its already in my post in the last paragraph - im just trying to figure out why it has to be that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about the framework, but about the TypeScript vs JavaScript. I guess you've used JavaScript modules when working with React. In Typescript the syntax is a bit different. To write what you want in typescript...

```js
class LoggerService {
 // ...
}
export { LoggerService };
```

You can read more about [TypeScript's modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Comment: as a follow up to this, does anyone really write code like this or is it frowned upon in general?

Comment: I'm working with a lot of angular lately and I usually write `export class ...` syntax. Also, I usually export only one item from the file, except for some utility functions or models (which are not coupled in a file with components/services/etc.), so for example `user.utils.ts` or `user.model.ts`.

Comment: It's a bit more convenient as new developers are usually used to the way it's written in docs.